# Find the volume of the solid by rotating the region bound by $y = 1 - x^2$, $y = 0$, and $x = 0$ about the line $y = 2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I am not really sure if I am on the right track right now. But I am supposed to find the volume of the solid.

My Attempt (Volumes of Revolution):

So I am given the following equations:
$$\begin{align*}
y = 1-x^2 \quad (1)\\
y = 0 \quad (2)\\
x = 0 \quad (3)
\end{align*}$$

So first, I tried to find the points of intersection of these equations. For (1) and (2), I let them equal to each other and found that they intersect at $x = \pm 1$. And for (1) and (3), I sub (3) to (1) and I found that they intersect at $y = 1$.

I am not exactly sure where to proceed from here. Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure what region exactly you're referring to if both $y=0$ and $x=0$ are bounds, there are two regions bounded by that set of curves - one in the first quadrant, one in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we must translate all points and curves $2$ units down, so we will end up rotating about the $x$ axis, which is manageable. So, the area we are concerned with is now bounded by the curves
$$\begin{align}
& x=0\\
& y=-2\\
& y=-1-x^2
\end{align}$$
Let's find the intersection points of the curves. Let $y=-2$. Then $x^2=1$ so $x=1$ (assuming you just mean the area bounded in the last quadrant, as there are $2$ possible quadrants you could be talking about, as noted in comments).

Hence the volume generated will be equal to

$$\pi\int_0^1 (-2)^2-(-1-x^2)^2dx$$
Can you finish? Please tell me if you need more help and I will be happy to comply.

Comment: Ah, translating the curves down is something I did not consider. I can probably solve the rest. Tyvm!

Comment: @user858034 You are really welcome, I'm glad I was able to help! You may accept my answer if it was very helpful btw ;)

Comment: Another quick question, due to symmetry, if I want to find from -1 to 1, then would it be $2\pi$ instead of $\pi$?

Comment: @user858034 exactly.

Comment: @user858034 you may also want to observe that the answer we obtain is the same as if the curves we were dealing with were reflected in the $x$ axis. Do you see why?